# Pergunta usando while

Tags: java, while

sou novo em java e gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês, meu código esta correto seguindo o exercício que estou fazendo, mas quero incrementar ele usando while para perguntar para o usuário se ele quer repetir o processo das perguntas... porem meu código não esta funcionando...

```Java
package Aula_02;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exe_11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        float rea1, rea2, rea3, rea4;
        char op;

        System.out.println("Informe o seu salario...");
        float salario = ler.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Deseja repetir a consulta (S / N)? : ");
        op = ler.next().charAt(0);

        if (op == 's' || op == 'S') {

            do {

                if (salario <= 280) {
                    rea1 = (float) (salario + (0.20 * salario));

                    System.out.println("**************************");
                    System.out.println("***Informativo de Salario***");
                    System.out.println("Salario base de: R$ " + salario);
                    System.out.println("O Percentual de Aumento é 20%");
                    System.out.println("O Valor do Aumento de: R$ " + 0.20 * salario);
                    System.out.println("Seu novo salario é de: R$ " + rea1);
                    System.out.println("**************************");

                } else if (salario > 280 && salario <= 700) {
                    rea2 = (float) (salario + (0.15 * salario));

                    System.out.println("**************************");
                    System.out.println("***Informativo de Salario***");
                    System.out.println("Salario base de: R$ " + salario);
                    System.out.println("O Percentual de Aumento é 15%");
                    System.out.println("O Valor do Aumento de: R$ " + 0.20 * salario);
                    System.out.println("Seu novo salario é de: R$ " + rea2);
                    System.out.println("**************************");

                } else if (salario > 700 && salario <= 1500) {
                    rea3 = (float) (salario + (0.10 * salario));

                    System.out.println("**************************");
                    System.out.println("***Informativo de Salario***");
                    System.out.println("Salario base de: R$ " + salario);
                    System.out.println("O Percentual de Aumento é 10%");
                    System.out.println("O Valor do Aumento de: R$ " + 0.10 * salario);
                    System.out.println("Seu novo salario é de: R$ " + rea3);
                    System.out.println("**************************");

                } else if (salario > 1500) {
                    rea4 = (float) (salario + (0.05 * salario));

                    System.out.println("**************************");
                    System.out.println("***Informativo de Salario***");
                    System.out.println("Salario base de: R$ " + salario);
                    System.out.println("O Percentual de Aumento é 5%");
                    System.out.println("O Valor do Aumento de: R$ " + 0.05 * salario);
                    System.out.println("Seu novo salario é de: R$ " + rea4);
                    System.out.println("**************************");

                }

            } while (op == 's' || op == 'S');

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você não está a ler a opção dentro do `do while`, então não há forma de sair desse `do while`, gerando um loop infinito.

O padrão que pode aplicar é:

```
char op;

do {
    //leitura do salario para poder mudar em cada repetição
    //codigo dos salarios

    System.out.println("Deseja repetir a consulta (S / N)? : "); //pergunta de novo
    op = ler.next().charAt(0); //lê de novo para que possa sair do while
} while (op == 's' || op == 'S');
```

Para alem disso, como o código dos salários é todo igual á exceção da percentagem, pode optimizar bastante o código com um método reutilize essa lógica para cada caso do `if` que tem.

Construindo esse método e aplicando o padrão acima o código ficava assim:

```
//generalização da logica que tava no while para um salario e uma percentagem
public static void mostraSalario(float salario, float percentagem){
    float rea = (float) (salario + (percentagem * salario));

    System.out.println("**************************");
    System.out.println("***Informativo de Salario***");
    System.out.println("Salario base de: R$ " + salario);
    System.out.println("O Percentual de Aumento é " + (percentagem*100) + "%");
    System.out.println("O Valor do Aumento de: R$ " + percentagem * salario);
    System.out.println("Seu novo salario é de: R$ " + rea);
    System.out.println("**************************");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    char op;

    do {
        System.out.println("Informe o seu salario...");
        //leitura do salario dentro do while para pedir novo salario a cada repetição
        float salario = ler.nextFloat(); 

        //cada if agora só chama o método passando o salario e a percentagem respetiva
        //mesmo as condições dos ifs foram simplificadas pois eram redundantes
        if (salario <= 280) {
            mostraSalario(salario, 0.20f);
        } else if (salario <= 700) { 
            mostraSalario(salario, 0.15f);
        } else if (salario <= 1500) {
            mostraSalario(salario, 0.10f);
        } else {
            mostraSalario(salario, 0.05f);
        }

        System.out.println("Deseja repetir a consulta (S / N)? : ");
        op = ler.next().charAt(0);

    } while (op == 's' || op == 'S');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Há na verdade 2 problemas:

1. Você precisa ler o salário dentro do loop, senão ele não muda nunca também.
2. A leitura da pergunta se quer continuar também precisa ser dentro do loop, porém no final dele.

O @Isac corrigiu os dois ali, mas não comentou do primeiro, só colocou um comentário no primeiro código.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!